# sqlalchemy flask return records with step

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have too man records in my database to draw a line chart.

```
 f = C1.query.all() 
 Data = [dict(id=r.id,timestamp=r.timestamp,qir=r.qir,so=r.so) for r in f]
```

I need to do this with a step. E.g. to take every 10 record (id=10, id=20, ... id=3000). But unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter using a modulus.

```
f = C1.query.filter(C1.id % 10 == 0).all()

data = [dict(id=r.id, timestamp=r.timestamp, qir=r.qir, so=r.so) for r in f]
```

Or, if you already have the set of all objects, you could just filter the ones with ids divisible by 10 by adding an `if` to your list comprehension:

```
f = C1.query.all()
data = [
    dict(
        id=r.id,
        timestamp=r.timestamp,
        qir=r.qir, so=r.so
    ) for r in f if r.id % 10 == 0
]
```